# can you use a tensorflow saved model made with python directly with Swift?

Tags: python, swift, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I have trained a tensorflow AI and saved the model to make predictions with python. I would like to port that model to SWIFT. Is it compatible straight out of the box ? (like importing the model saved file) or should we re-code the trainning process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, as of late December 2019-early January 2020, saving/loading models natively in Swift for TensorFlow (S4TF) is in the works. As @dynamicwebpaige said in this S4TF Google Group [discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/swift/NrNtW7SuPLs) recently, the team is working to implement a TensorFlow C++ API, primarily focused on SavedModel inference with ETA 1Q 2020. In the same discussion, one user shared a S4TF > Keras (via Python interop) > CoreML (for Apple apps) [demo link](https://github.com/meirrosendorff/tensorForSwiftModels). Additionally, there's a [presentation](http://static.brettkoonce.com/presentations/machine_learning_mobile_recap.pdf) you may find useful.